# How to pull information from classes through raw input

Tags: python, python-2.7, game-development

I'm well into development of a text-based RPG.  Right now, my store system is very long and convoluted, in that there is a lot repeated code.  The idea I currently have going on is that I have a list of items available to sell, and based off raw input from the user, it will related those items to if / else statements, assuming I have the proper item and player classes made, i.e.:

```
store = ['sword', 'bow', 'health potion']
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Type the name of the item you want to buy: ")
    lst = [x for x in store if x.startswith(inp)
    if len(lst) == 0:
        print "No such item."
        continue
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        item = lst[0]
        break
    else:
        print "Which of the following items did you mean?: {0}".format(lst)
        continue
if item == 'sword':
    user.inventory['Weapons'].append(sword.name)
    user.strength += sword.strength
    user.inventory['Gold'] -= sword.cost
elif item == 'bow'
    #Buy item
#Rest of items follow this if statement based off the result of item.
```

As you can see, I'm using the result of the 'item' variable to determine a line of if / elif / else statements for each item, and what happens if that item name is equal to the variable 'item'.

Instead, I want the player to be able to type in the item name, and then for that raw input to be translated to class names.  In other words, if I typed in 'sword', I want Python to pull the information from the 'sword' object class, and apply those values to the player.  For example, a weapon's damage is transferred to the player's skill.  If a sword does 5 strength damage, the player's strength will be raised by 5.  How can I get python to add the values of one class to another without a shit ton of if / else statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all your game item classes names in a single place (for example, a module), you can use Python's getattr to retrieve the class itself having its string.

SO, for example, let's suppose you have a items.py file that does something like:

```
from weapons import Sword, Bow, Axe, MachinneGun
from medicine import HealthPotion, MaxHealthPotion, Poison, Antidote
```

(or just define those classes right there in the `items` module)
You can there proceed to do:

```
import items
...
inp = raw_input("Type the name of the item you want to buy: ")
...
item_class = getattr(items, inp)

user.inventory.append(item_class.__name__)
if hasattr(item_class, strength):
    user.strength += item_class.strength
```

and so on.

You can also simply create a dictionary:

```
from items import Sword, Bow, HealthPotion
store = {"sword: Sword, "bow": Bow, "health potion": HealthPotion} 
...
item_class = store[inp]
...
```

Note that the text is quoted- it is text data, and the unquoted values are the actual Python classes- which have all the attributes and such.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!  When I use the getattr method, Python returns an error message saying that the 'Item' object, from my Item class, has no attribute '__name__'.  What does it mean by that?

Comment: That should be a separate question. Also on top of the pretty good answer given, you will need some kind of validation of the entered data/exception catching to finish the "store" feature.

Comment: The code above assumes it is picking attribtues from classes of items - if they are already instantiated, the instances don't have a `__name__` attribute. But you can use `item.__class__.__name__`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno), my code now works.  Here is my official fix using his dictionary method:

```
from objects import ironsword
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, strength):
        self.strength = strength
        self.inventory = []

user = player(10)
store = {'iron longsword': ironsword}
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Type the name of the item you want to buy: ")
    lst = [x for x in store if x.startswith(inp)]
    if len(lst) == 0:
        print "No such item."
        continue
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        item = lst[0]
        break
    else:
        print "Which of the following items did you mean?: {0}".format(lst)
        continue
item_class = store[item]
user.inventory.append(item_class.name)
user.strength += item_class.strength
print user.inventory
print user.strength
```

Typing even 'iron' into the raw input will pull the correct item.  When printing user.inventory, it returns the correct item name, e.g. `['iron longsword']`, and when printing the user strength variable, it prints the repsective amount.